# Books about old Operating systems

Tags: operating-systems, books

where can i find very old books about old operating systems like CP/M and DOS and other OS that worked on the 8086 ??

second question isn't old books 20 year before and older should have an expired patent ??
where in general can i find books of expired patents ...

thanx

Comment: Books are not patented: they are copyrighted. Copyright doesn't expire until 75 years after the death of the last author.

Answer (score 2):

it's perfectly possible to buy one on amazon:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/CP-M-Handbook-Rodnay-Zaks/dp/0895880482/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1420360499&sr=1-1&keywords=cp%2Fm

Comment: is this book about how the os works ? or is it about how to use it ? I want something explaining the internals. am a student but i want to learn os gradually not using today;s standard text it describes too complex os

Comment: perhaps you should look into minix instead; www.minix3.org

Answer (score 2):

[PC Magazine Programmers Technical Reference: The Processor and Coprocessor by Rob Hummel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1562760165) and [Microcomputer Architecture and Programming by John F. Wakerly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471853194) are older books which go into detail about the 6800 family of cpus and their design. The PC Magazine one is more of a reference book though.

These books detail the CPU design and operand calls in machine code that the OS uses to control the computer. This would describe the underlying functionality of a computer, as an OS has many parts (even an old one) there is more than one topic or theory at play to allow an OS to exist.